# Chrome 69 when using 'transform', '-webkit-background-clip: text' and 'color:transparent' don't work

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-image, transform

CSS code :

```css
.test {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e74c3c 20%, #f4d03f 40%, #2ecc71 60%, #5dade2 80%, #a569bd 100%);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">abcde</span>
```

[image]

but with 'transform',

```css
.test {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e74c3c 20%, #f4d03f 40%, #2ecc71 60%, #5dade2 80%, #a569bd 100%);
  transform-origin: 0;
  transform: scale(1.2); /*any attributes*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">abcde</span>
```

It will not work.
the result is:

[image: not working]

The version of chrome is 69. Can some one tell me why this does not work?

Comment: Yes that's a bug, you might want to let them know about it before it makes its way to the stable channel. FWIW, it seems the clipped layer gets transformed twice or alike (visible by not setting color to transparent), at least on my v70.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently nested divs were not a problem before for `-webkit-background-clip` but in Chrome 69 it doesn't work.

```css
.test {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e74c3c 20%, #f4d03f 40%, #2ecc71 60%, #5dade2 80%, #a569bd 100%);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">I'M VISIBLE</span>

<span class="test">
  <div>
     I'M NOT VISIBLE IN CHROME 69
  </div>
</span>

<span class="test">
     I'M ALSO NOT VISIBLE IN CHROME 69
  <div>
     I'M NOT VISIBLE IN CHROME 69
  </div>
</span>
```

The snippet above works fine for all the cases in Firefox (v62) and Chrome Canary(v71)

**EDIT** Safari (v11) has the same behaviour as chrome 69, just the first case on the snippet works

**EDIT 2** If you are using the divs to achieve new lines, replacing the divs with `<br/>` is a possible workaround.

```css
.test {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #e74c3c 20%, #f4d03f 40%, #2ecc71 60%, #5dade2 80%, #a569bd 100%);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">I'M VISIBLE</span>

<span class="test">
  <br/>
     I'M NOW VISIBLE IN CHROME 69 & Safari (v11) 
</span>

<span class="test">
     I'M ALSO NOW VISIBLE IN CHROME 69 & Safari (v11) 
  <br/>
     I'M NOW VISIBLE IN CHROME 69 & Safari (v11) 
</span>
```