# -webkit-background-clip: text no longer works in Chrome 69

Tags: css, google-chrome

I just realized, that in Chrome 69 the behavior for `-webkit-background-clip: text;` changed. It now has the same bug as Edge. When the content is wrapped in paragraphs, the text is invisible.

What I want to achieve is that I have a gradient in the background and transparent text color, so that the color of the gradient comes through. This works in Firefox and used to work in Chrome, but now, in version 69, it no longer works.

Here is a codepen to try it out: https://codepen.io/obs/pen/eLPeYz
When you delete the p tags, it works as supposed to.

Is this a bug in Chrome? How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned that the bug does not happen when you have nested inline elements. So adjusting *obs* codepen to use span tags instead of p tags the clipping works.

Comment: That's true. Or just change the display of the p tags. So I can restore the intended behaviour like that: `p{ display: inline; } p::after { content: "\A\A"; white-space: pre; }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this seems to be a bug in Chrome. Others have reported it also: [Chrome 69 when using 'transform', '-webkit-background-clip: text' and 'color:transparent' don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924130/chrome-69-when-using-transform-webkit-background-clip-text-and-colortra)

Also, good practice is to put `-webkit-background-clip: text;` on an element that has text in it, not on it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: linear-gradient(#131c27, #663b34);
background-clip: text;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
```

This works in chrome. just set your gradient and then use the rest of the code in css.

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking to see if anyone else was experiencing trouble `webkit-background-clip: text;`. I noticed the code for making text gradients worked on text inside buttons but when I applied the same code to h1 text it did not work. After some experimentation I discovered that adding `width` before the background linear gradient solved the issue for me.

I know these answers are a couple of years old, but should someone like me looks here again, the following worked for me:

```html
<style>
     h1 { text-align:center; font-family: 'Italiana', serif; 
     font-size: 2em; width:50%; background: linear-gradient( 
     to right, rgba(206, 189, 167, .55), rgba(247, 241, 226, 
     1), rgba(206, 189, 167, .55)); 
     -webkit-background-clip: text;
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
     background-clip: text; padding: 1em 0 1em 0; }
</style>
```

View my gradient text at: https://palmbeachcuisine.com/#BreakfastandBrunch